# How to run php page script without cronjob

Tags: javascript, php, database, cron

I want to run a PHP script every 5 seconds without using cronjobs. How is it possible in PHP?

I want to update user data every 5 seconds. The program will execute when I refresh the page but I want to run that script if the page is open or not in browser.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Not possible without at least one browser running a page

Comment: So you want to schedule jobs without using a job scheduler. Why?

Comment: why don't you want to use cron? It is absolutely perfect for the task "Do xyz every minute/monday/year etc.".

Comment: Cronjob I placed on my cpanel every minute but my service provider refused use every minute cronjob.am thinking any other way is there or not

Comment: Why would you want to update user data every 5 seconds? As long as there are no external changes, there is nothing to update so you might as well update when something actually changes.

Comment: Then how about running the cronjob in greater intervals but the loop some more in e.g. a php script to compensate for the time?

Comment: in simple words "NOT POSSIBLE"

Comment: Agree with @jeroen five seconds is ridiculous. I don't think anyone updates that often. Some pages even load slower than 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to have a text file or a database entry that holds the time of the last run in UNIX time.
Then on all (or selected) pages you add something like;

```
If($lastrun +5 < strtotime(now)){
    //Run the user update 
}
```

This means when a user or visitor on your page goes to one of the "selected" pages with the code above this visitor will "run the update"

Answer (score 0):

You must have some basics about PHP. PHP only runs when you request a page. So it's impossible to run php without requesting the page. Somehow you must reload the page every 5 seconds then you can run it every 5 sec.

So you must use cron or something like this. Or, you can you can use an old computer (NOT RECOMMENDED) which will relaod the page. To relaod the page you can use browser plugins like auto reload (for chrome).

But almost every hosting companies provide free cron job. Please search your cpanel for that. Or, mail your hosting provider for help. Cron is the best way to do this job for free.

Comment: Why use auto reload (or any plugin) when you can use meta refresh that is part of very basic html supported by all browsers?

Comment: ups! I forgot that thing!.. Thanks!